# System Restore is not creating restore points

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore

On my Windows 8.1 system, System Restore is not automatically creating restore points when programs are installed or uninstalled or at specified intervals. I have enough free space on the disk. What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is that it is switched on correctly:

1. `Windows key + X` to get menu - choose System.
2. Choose `Advanced system settings` from left menu.
3. Pick `System Protection` tab. (It will tell you here if its on or not)
4. Choose `Configure` and check settings.

Comment: Yes it is switched on. I can manually configure a restore point, too.

Comment: On this same screen - does the "Create..." button work? Also, if you run system restore from here, is it showing any restore points at all? (may need to check "Show more.." at bottom)

Comment: Yes, and yes. '

Comment: something I found - Double check to make sure the services below are enabled and set to Automatic. Afterwards, try again to see if that may help.

"Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider" and

"Volume Shadow Copy"

Comment: Have just done a little research on this - apparently there is a known Microsoft bug with system restore which is meant to be fixed via an update - http://www.windowsbbs.com/windows-8/104955-restore-points-not-being-created.html - 3rd to last answer. For the minute, I would look at using task manager to do it.

Comment: How to do this on windows 8- http://www.pcandtablet.com/windows-8-system-backup-and-restore/438/how-to-create-a-periodic-system-restore-point-using-schedule-task-in-windows-8-a.html - Windows 8.1 should be almost identical. Not ideal answer I'm afraid.